# this.$ in jquery / javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm just getting started in Javascript, Backbone and jQuery.  I am running into some code that looks like this:

```
someBackboneFunction: function () {
    this.$('#index1').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}
```

This function is declared in a backbone view subclass.  From what I gather, this is referring to the function context of the object that gets created with this backbone view.  The view that has this function declared is created with the `new` keyword.  If that is correct, I'm not sure what

```
this.$('#index1')
```

actually means.  Does it just mean that on the object itself that was created with the `new` keyword, find the index1 id and disable it?  Thanks!

Comment: http://backbonejs.org/#View-dollar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.$('#index1')` is finding an element that matches the selector, `#index1`, as a child of the view's element itself.

For use within a view, there will be a `this.$el` that represents the view's element, wrapped as a jQuery object. `this.$('selector')` is the same as `this.$el.find('selector')`.

Comment: so does that mean that this.$ is a backbone thing only?  It's not used in traditional jquery?  (e.g. $('#myelementtofind')

Comment: Kind of! `this.$` in a Backbone view is just a fancy way of scoping the jQuery selector to the view's matching element, and not the entire document, which is the default context when using jQuery.  Were you to go to any random website that has jQuery (this one included), pop open the console in the dev tools, and type in `this.$('div')`, you will be using jQuery the same as if you said `this.$('div')` or `$('div')`, since `$` is on the root, `window` scope. The `this` in a Backbone view refers to itself-- the view. And the View object has a property called `$` on it. Hope this is helping!

Comment: yes very helpful!  So you can essentially do this.$ on any page, not just a backbone view.  (I'm still trying to read up on scoping and it's not totally clear yet).

Comment: @Crystal—note that `this`  may reference a different object (or anything at all in strict mode) depending on how the current execution context was established. You can write `this.$` only where `this` references an object with a `$` property that references jQuery. If you don't fully understand how `this` works in javascript (noting that it doesn't have anything to do with scope), you should do some research (e.g. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)).

Answer (score 0):

From what I remember in Backbone `this.$` is a wrapper for jQuery and it allows you to select elements in the scope of your view.

So `this.$('#index1')` should mean "select `#index1` in my view" and `.attr('disabled', 'disabled')` sets its disabled attribute to true.